# TypeError: data() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'n', 'p', 'gn', and 's'

Tags: python

I have this assignment for school work, this is pretty basic stuff i gather but I'm new to this language so I'm still a little nooby. I get the aforementioned error upon testing each module with the error being specific to this line and this line alone.

```
def data(n, p, gn, s):

    name[x] = input("Please enter the customer's name.")
    n.append(name[x])

    phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
    if len.str(phone[x]) == 11:
        p.append(attendance[x])
    else :  phone[x] = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
    if len.str(phone[x]) == 11:
        p.append(attendance[x])

    groupno[x] = int(input("Please enter the number of diners in the group - length must be 11 characters."))
    if  1 >= groupno[x] <=20:
        gn.append(groupno[x])
    else:  groupno[x] = int(input("Please enter the number of diners in the group - between 1 & 20."))
    gn.append(groupno[x])

    score[x] = int(input("Please enter the rating of the meal."))
    if 1 >= score[x] <=3:
        s.append(score[x])
    else:  score[x] = int(input("Please enter the rating of the meal - between 1 & 10."))
    if 1 >= score[x] <=3:
        s.append(score[x])
data()
```

Comment: Last line of yoru code is calling `data()` without any parameters even though you've specified four positional arguments, `n, p, gn, s`.

Comment: You also might want to use more descriptive name for you parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to store information about multiple customers, I suggest you use a dictionary instead:

```
def data():
   name = input("Please enter the customer's name.")
   temp_phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
   while len.str(temp_phone) != 11:
        temp_phone = int(input("Please enter the customer's Phone Number."))
   phone = temp_phone
   temp_groupno = int(input("Please enter the number of diners in the group (maximum 20 diners)"))
   while  not (1 <= groupno <=20):
        temp_groupno = int(input("Please enter the number of diners in the group (maximum 20)"))
   group = temp_groupno

   temp_score = int(input("Please enter the rating of the meal (between 1 and 10)"))
   while not (1 <= temp_score <= 3):
        temp_score = int(input("Please enter the rating of the meal - between 1 & 10."))
   score = temp_score
   return {'name': name, 'phone': phone, 'group': group, 'score': score}

customers = []
customers.append(data())
customers.append(data())
print(customers)
```

Comment: Thank you dude, will give it a go ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your function require 4 parameters and you have given it none.

When you define a function like so: `def foo(a,b,c,d)`, you need to supply it with `a,b,c` and `d`.

```
name[x] = input("Please enter the customer's name.")
    n.append(name[x])
```

This will also give you an error as `x` is undefined.